# Styling a div's links in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I would like to change the style of an element's links using JavaScript. The CSS would look like:

```
#element a:link {
    color: #000;
}
```

I know that you can change the style of the the element itself, as in:

```
elementObject.style.color = '#000';
```

Pseudo-code for what I want would be:

```
                 |
                 V
elementObject.[A:LINK].style.color = "#ff0000";
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe the new [HTML5 selectors API](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/) might fit your use case.

Comment: Have a look at jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the :link :visited are not true CSS elements, but part of the CSS rule, this means you need to edit the rule, change the rule or apply another class...

```
var css='#element a:link { color: #ff0000 }';
style=document.createElement('style');
if (style.styleSheet)
    style.styleSheet.cssText=css;
else 
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

Comment: Makes sense... I think applying a new class will actually suit what I need nicely... thank you!

Comment: ya that's the approach I would take too :) I also wanted to put it in the answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through links and set the one by one.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function new_window()
{
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++)
    {
        anchors[i].style.color = '#000';
    }
}
window.onload = new_window;
</script>
```

The other way to create a wrapper `div` with the "wrapper" class name. Then replace its class name to "wrapper2" with JavaScript. After then the rules in the CSS like `.wrapper a` will be activated.

```
.wrapper a
{
    //normal code
}
.wrapper2 a
{
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't really answer the question

Comment: just updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

select **visited links** is javascript isnt possible merely by a selector. have a look at [Detect Visited Link In Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394099/detect-visited-link-in-chrome)

and this http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Visited

so if you wanna set the style of a visited/unvisited link using javascript loop through all the links in the body. checking wether they are visited and then apply style.

```
var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0;i<as.length;i++){
//check and set the style here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function addCss(sel, css){
    S= document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length-1];
    var r= (S.cssRules!= undefined)? S.cssRules: S.rules;
    if(S.insertRule) S.insertRule(sel+'{'+css+'}',r.length);
    else if(S.addRule)S.addRule(sel,css,r.length);
}

 addCss('button:hover','background-color:blue;');
```